# Is there a way to create $2^n$ factorial designs in R (similar to minitab)?

Tags: r, experimental-design

I am working on creating a $2^n$ design (not randomized). I have done $2^5$ by hand, but I must now do $2^7$ and $2^8$. I know in Minitab there's a design generator that will list out all of the treatments / factors but I do not have access to Minitab. Is there an R package that will do the same thing?

For example, if said dream function was called "2n" and I input:

```
2to2 <-- 2n(2)
```

or something, the output would be:

```
2to2

A   B  AB
0   0   1
1   0   0
0   1   0
1   1   1
```

... does that make sense?

*edited to add: I see the `FrF2` package, but I can't seem to get a good grasp of it. Anyone familiar with it or others?*

SOLVED:  `FrF2(nfactors = 8, resolution=8, randomize=FALSE)`

Answer (score 6):

This kind of question you can answer by yourself by going to CRAN, look at the taskviews (they are in the sidebar, near the top), and choose the 
ExperimentalDesign taskview.

Then you will find that package DoE.base probably will do what you want, there are some other packages you can look into as well, so as:
FrF2
BHH2

You should take a look at this packages in the order I have given here!

Comment: if you notice in my question, i solved it about a few mins after i posted. i kept fighting frf2 until it worked for me. but thanks!

Comment: @doesleuth For a complete design you can simply use the expand.grid() function, without calling any package